# Accessing elements of a struct instance variable in Objective-C using the getter

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have an instance variable which is a struct, for example:

```
struct Data {
    UInt32 i;
    UInt32 arr[1];
};
```

And a property is defined in my class:

```
@property struct Data data; // and the corresponding @synthesize in the imp file
```

Now, I am aware that changing the values of `i` and `arr` through the **getter** of `data` is conceptually wrong, since I will be accessing the copy of `data` returned by the getter (the correct way is accessing it using `self->data`).

However some general Objective-C questions arise regarding the following lines:

```
self.data.i = 1;      // produces compile error        
self.data.arr[0] = 1; // compiles ok
```

First, why does the first line produces a compile error, and the 2nd line does not?

Second, if the dot syntax in the above line (`self.data`) is just a syntactic sugar to `[self data]`, why do I get 2 different (although similar) compile errors?

```
self.data.i = 1;   // error: Expression is not assignable
[self data].i = 1; // error: Semantic Issue: Assigning to 'readonly' return result of an objective-c message not allowed
```

Comment: This is the same reason self.frame.size = CGSizeMake(320,460) doesn't work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually, structs are passed by value in C (and Objective C). That means that your property actually returns a *read only copy* (rvalue) of the internal "Data" type. The assignment is to the temporary returned copy, which the compiler (rightfully) flags as a bit suspect.

The second line that compiles correctly does so since `self.data.arr` returns a read only UInt32*, but when you index it with [0] and write to that, you're not writing to the pointer, you're writing to the memory that it points to which is allowed.

Comment: Yes, this is clear from the error message, but how come the 2nd line compiles ok?

Comment: @ItamarKatz Missed that part, added some info clarifying that to the answer.

Comment: @ItamarKatz The second statement compiles and works because `self.data.arr` returns a pointer to a C array, an element of which you then modify. In other words, you're not modifying the internal struct's fields.

Comment: Thanks, it's clear now. Coming form c++, it's like the difference between a `const int *` and `int * const`